# jQuery trigger on element that is added after page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, element

I have an jQuery ajax form. When it's completed, it changed the ID of an element like this:

```
jQuery('#ready').attr('id','done');
```

Then, I want to do a `mouseover()` function targeting `#done`. The problem is that it does not work because #done was not loaded on page load.

What is the normal solution to this issue?

Comment: dont change the elements `id`, use a class instead (`addClass()`, `removeClass()` and `toggleClass()`)

Comment: You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use event-[delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#done', function(){
    //do something
});
```

You're appending content to your DOM **after the event-listener for your mouseover on `#done` is registered**. So this element does not exist at the time your binding an event to it.

Through event-delegation you are able to bind an event-listiner to an **existing parent** (`document` in this case). And this will listen to all events of its descendants matching the `#done` - selector.

Comment: This is great explanation, thank you. Will accept in a moment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this approach:

```
$( document ).on( 'mouseover', '#done', function() {
   //...
});
```

In this case your function handler will be attached to `document` and on `mouseover` it will search for `#done` element to fire.

Comment: Can you please explain this further?